# LED Light panels - Selecting the right driver for less flicker

Tags: led-driver

I'm in the process of helping a friend who is a photographer.

She has been using LED lights (OLD) with no issues.

[image]

She recently bought new lights (NEW), but noticed much more flicker, making it impossible to take photos.

[image]

I took OLD LED Driver and installed it on the NEW LED light panel and no more flicker.

[image]

Questions :

1. Is this safe to do as the LED panels and drivers are slightly different?
2. What is the main difference in the LED driver that affects the flicker?
3. When I buy more LED drivers, what specification am I looking for?

Comment: Put a filter across the input to the LED's: A small inductance in series, and a moderate size capacitor in parallel with the lamp. The inductor is to help prevent damage to some supplies because of the heavy initial current drawn by the cap.

Comment: Does the flicker problem lie with her eyes or the range of shutter speeds she is using?

Answer (score 3):

The old driver (0.9A) is running the diodes a lot brighter than the new one (0.55A).  The compliance voltages also do not match, which means you are running the driver out of spec.  Why not buy a new driver with the right voltage/current for the diodes you're driving?

Problems with flicker are common in cheaper LED drivers that use PWM for dimming, or that have poor ripple at maximum brightness.  Get a quality driver and do not use dimming (unless you are certain that it is not PWM dimming) and you won't have these problems.

Comment: For the drivers in the question, flickering is not caused by PWM. Totally the APFC technique inside the LED driver leads to flickering.

Answer (score 2):

> When I buy more LED drivers, what specification am I looking for?

Unfortunately, it tends not to be specified, at least not for small quantity domestic uses. Some drivers have vague assertions of 'less flicker', and 'no flicker', but they're not quantified, and how far can you trust them? There is a standardised method and nomenclature for describing it, but I don't have a reference to hand at the moment. I'm sure that if you were a large customer, you could work with a particular manufacturer to get exactly what you wanted.

There are two sources of flicker. PWM dimming is one source. The other is twice the mains frequency, where inadequate hold-up occurs during the zero-crossing period. A large value capacitor across the LED panel will smooth the supply current and so reduce the flicker. Some drivers might object to the apparent 'short circuit' of a large capacitor at switch-on, so additional components may be needed to allow it to start up.

I am cursed with 'fast eyes', so have done a fair bit of experimentation on this. I've used a photodiode and oscilloscope to record the instantaneous brightness of the LEDs. So far, of the lamps that I've tested, only V-TAC branded lamps have lived up to their claim of 'no flicker', which is not measureable accurately by me, perhaps <2% variation. Some lamps using the very cheap 'series cap and rectifier' circuit have come in with less than 30% variation (brightness varies 70% to 100%) during a mains cycle, which I find just tolerable.

The two main problems are that reducing the flicker costs money, and that the proportion of the population that can see it, or get upset by it, is very small, so we have very little market power. I can tell when I'm following a VW car at night, the tail lights flicker. Why has a large vehicle manufacturer been allowed to put millions of cars on the road that cause distress to <1% of the population, no other manufacturer uses PWM that slow?

It's very easy to make a flicker-free LED driver, but it will have a higher component cost than one that performs OK for the vast majority of the population.

Comment: About "fast eyes": Note that when making photos, shutter speed versus flicker frequency also comes in to play. A photo taken at 1/1000s will have to "see" at least one, preferably several, full "flicker periods" to get in the amount of light expected, so a few kHz is required. Some expensive cameras can actually sync with the flicker to give constant exposures. Also, you can have great fun going to the police with night photos of VWs driving around with no tail lights, if you are evil enough to do so.

Answer (score 1):

> Is this safe to do as the LED panels and drivers are slightly different?

Nope. Even if they both had the same power levels, we don't know the LED configurations inside those panels, so we don't know if they can be replacements for each other. Also, looking at the drivers' output currents, I see that SUNLED has 550mA and LEDVANCE has 900mA. And you tried to drive the SUNLED panel, which should be driven with 550mA, with 900mA. You could have harmed the panel.

Most of the LED panels are being sold with matching LED driver.

> What is the main difference in the LED driver that affects the flicker?

Totally the electronic design of the driver.

**Technical explanation:** Most of today's cheap commercial high-PF *(i.e. power factor(\$\lambda\$) is greater than or equal to 0.9)* LED drivers have a combo-controller *(Active Power Factor Correction + LED current regulator)* chip inside. The input voltage is a sine wave, and those chips' power factor correction mechanism leads the output current to have a ripple that is proportional to \$\sin^2(\omega)\$ (or \$\cos(2\omega)\$). This ripple show itself as 100Hz-flickers for 50Hz mains, or 120Hz-flickers for 60Hz mains.

I surely can say that almost all Low-PF *(i.e. power factor(\$\lambda\$) is lower than 0.9 -- generally \$\lambda\$ = ~0.6)* LED drivers are non-flickering types. Also, it's not uncommon to see non-isolated non-flickering LED drivers. But, you should be more careful when using them as they are not isolated from mains.

> When I buy more LED drivers, what specification am I looking for?

If you want to buy as a replacement, you should check if the operating voltage range (220V or 110V), LED driver type (Constant-current or constant-voltage), maximum output power (\$P_o\$ in Watts), output voltage range (\$U_o\$ or \$V_o\$ in Volts), and output current (\$I_o\$ in milliAmperes or Amperes) match the reference one.

Most of the LED drivers having an output power of at least 24W are high-PF ones. As I stated above, most of those have flickering output, and it's not that easy to determine if a driver is a non-flickering type. So you may need to either request a particularly non-flickering one from the seller or directly test with your LED panel.

Answer (score 1):

> When I buy more LED drivers, what specification am I looking for?

These are constant current drivers. For example the "SUNLED" one outputs 500-550mA. An important parameter is the output voltage compliance. The label indicates "U:37-44V" which means it will regulate current to 500-550mA only if the LED voltage is within that range. If output voltage is outside of the 37-44V range it won't work correctly. The mention "Uout:51VDC" is the maximum output voltage with no or low load.

So the new driver should have the same regulated current, and same or wider output voltage range.

> Is this safe to do as the LED panels and drivers are slightly different?

If you use a driver that outputs more current, the LEDs may overheat. If you use a driver with an output voltage range that doesn't correspond to the LEDs, it will probably not work or blink.

> What is the main difference in the LED driver that affects the flicker?

As usual, the reason is cost. At this power, Power Factor Correction is not mandatory, so you'll usually get a rectifier, smoothing caps, followed by a switching converter. It costs more to have enough smoothing caps to make it not flicker.

Here are two examples of suitable drivers: [APC-25](https://www.meanwell-web.com/content/files/pdfs/productPdfs/MW/APC-25/APC-25-spec.pdf) and [IDLC-25](https://www.meanwell-web.com/content/files/pdfs/productPdfs/MW/IDLC-25/IDLC-25-spec.pdf), you should be able to get these pretty much anywhere. The latter is dimmable, which could be handy.

To get a flicker-free driver, you'll want to check if the datasheet mentions "flicker-free", or even better if it mentions a low value of **output voltage ripple** or **output current ripple**. If it is dimmable, also check it doesn't use PWM for dimming, but instead varies the output current. The ones I link should do what you want.